# Would it reflect badly on a new employee to ask for documents not given on joining day?

Tags: software-industry, hiring-process, new-job

I have just started my career in the IT field. I got my offer letter on the day of the interview. I was told to get my appointment letter on the joining day. It has been three days since I joined, and I haven't got my appointment letter yet.

Should I continue to wait for it, or ask for it now? Would it lead to any bad impression or make them think I am in a hurry if I ask?

Comment: sounds more like a company specific question but no harm in checking with HR.

Comment: This is my first company I'm working with so I don't know a much about that.

Comment: So call HR or whoever  on boarded you on first day and ask them. You will get  a straight answer.

Comment: Ok I will call Them I just wanted to know if that would make me look in hurry or pose any kind of bad impression.

Comment: people have lot of questions on their first week, especially the fresh grads. This is their all day job. While this is a perfectly valid question, even if it was not, they will not e time to make a judgement on you based on your question. They will just give you an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't overthink this. Just ask the HR person or your manager.

Onboarding is a rather lengthy process (especially for first time employees due to the additional paperwork required), and it is not unusual for relatively lower priority steps to be deferred to later.

It appears that as per your company's policy, the onboarding team is supposed to give you the appointment letter on the joining day. However, it is not of utmost urgency, so they may have decided to hand it over to you later.

There won't be any undesirable consequences for you in future, provided you don't screw up badly how you ask for it. Don't mention "you were supposed to give me the appointment letter 3 days ago". From your question, it is clear you are actually not complaining about the delay, so don't make it *unintentionally* sound like you are complaining.

> When shall I come over to collect my appointment letter?

Now, if they had forgotten about the appointment letter, they get to save face. They can simply respond with a date when the letter would be ready, or inform you that it would be sent through internal mail.

Comment: Said otherwise : bureaucracy may take time, and is not so important. Don't burn your career on this. +1000

Comment: Yep, don't make it a demand

Answer (score 2):

Continue to ask for it periodically until you get what was promised.

Sometimes people forget, sometimes things get lost in the shuffle, sometimes it just takes a little time.

Assume positive intent here. Try not to be accusatory and try to be patient.

As @llewellyn points out - Be careful about how you word the question, though, so you don't come across as demanding or annoying. A friendly reminder shouldn't hurt, though, even if you have to use it repeatedly.

Comment: Be careful about how you word the question, though, so you don't come across as demanding or annoying. A friendly reminder shouldn't hurt, though, even if you have to use it repeatedly.